# Why does only part of information get uploaded into databse?

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, spring-boot

Saw many questions made of this type though none really answered in my case. I'm making a simple spring boot server that should work like a storage for liquor. One of my rest calls is to take the order, write it into db and update the products. I managed to get the part of writing in the order right, though there is no change on my products even when there is no sign of an error(one other rest call runs on almost same code as the part that updates products and works fine). I'm out of ideas but my assumption is that the query is wrong, that being said i still can't find what exactly is the mistake.

Here is some of my code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/new")
public void newOrder(@RequestBody Orders order) {
    orderService.newOrder(order);
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Override
public void newOrder(Orders order) {
    for (Product product : order.getProduct()) {
        productRepository.orderProducts(product.getId(), product.getAmount());
    }
    Orders newOrder = new Orders(
            order.getProduct());
   ordersRepository.save(newOrder);
}
```

Product repository:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Product p set p.amount = (p.amount - :amount) where p.id = :id")
void orderProducts(int id, int amount);
```

Order entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp date;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders")
private List<Product> product;
```

Product entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String brandName;

private int price;

private int mass;

private int alcohol;

@Lob
private byte[] picture;

private int amount;

@ManyToMany
private List<Orders> orders;
```

And my rest call on postman:

```
{

    "product": [

        {
    "id": 1,
    "brandName": "pivo",
    "price": 23,
    "mass": 1,
    "alcohol": 47,
    "amount": 123,
    "orders": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "brandName": "pivo",
    "price": 23,
    "mass": 1,
    "alcohol": 47,
    "picture": null,
    "amount": 58,
    "orders": []
}   

        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `value` attribute in the `@Query` annotation.

Change your query to this:

```
@Query( value = "update Product p set p.amount = (p.amount - :amount) where p.id = :id")
```

Comment: There’s no need to do this. If you are only configuring a single attribute it is assumed to be the `value` attribute.

Comment: Tried it, didn't change a thing.

Comment: Nothing, everything stayed the same.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, though if I understood the question correctly here is what server writes out after the fail: https://ibb.co/12hNqc1

Comment: I think query is working fine.! Make sure you parameter are updated in db.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the error finally. Seems that it kept saying that the id is 0 so it couldn't update the db probably because of the @GeneratedValue. I added an another variable that is basically another id but with values in it. Heard that it can be dealt with far cleaner with some sort of view object, though i have no idea how to use that.